# Magento1: How to detect if configurable product has dynamical price?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

Some configurable products look like simple product but with sizes or swatches options in it where the price is not changed.

Others configurable products have flexible price which depends on options.

How to detect the difference between these types of configurable products?

I have an idea to just loop all simple products and compare the finalprice but its enough expensive by resources.